# Как записать/считать динамическую структуру в бинарный файл?

Tags: c, структуры

Имеется структура:

```
struct books{
    char a[128];
    char b[128];
    char c[128];
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    int century;
} *ptr;
```

Как в Си записать и считать динамическую структуру данных в бинарный файл?

Comment: fread/fwrite? (если только пустот нет в структуре)

Comment: @KoVadim Каким образом это будет выглядеть? Можно пример?

Comment: https://www.cpp.com.ru/shildt_spr_po_c/09/0905.html

Answer (score 0):

```
struct books{
    char a[128];
    char b[128];
    char c[128];
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    int century;
} *ptr;

fwrite(ptr,sizeof(*ptr),1,file);

fread(ptr,sizeof(*ptr),1,file);
```

`ptr` должен указывать на реальную структуру в памяти, которую записываем и в которую читаем.